# CFG for L {a^nb^m | n <= m+3}

Tags: context-free

I need a Context Free Grammar for this language. I could come up with this solution:

```
S -> AB
A -> aA | ε
B -> bbbB | ε
```

But, this grammar is clearly wrong, since the number of a's can still exceed the number of b's. How do I draw a link between the two variables A and B such that $n\leq m+3$?

P.S. It is a humble request to anyone who downvotes this question to please specify the reason in the comments below

Comment: Create up to 3 a’s. Then repeatedly either create ab  or b.

Comment: @gnasher729 sorry I couldn't get it, could you write an answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [gnasher729's](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/108653/cfg-for-l-anbm-n-m3#comment232079_108653) comment, I came up with the following CFG that I believe meet the requirements:

$$
S \to AAAB \\
A \to a \;|\; \varepsilon\\
B \to aBb \;|\; Bb \;|\; \varepsilon
$$

Comment: looks fine to me too

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to come up with a CFG directly. A better approach can be, making a PDA and converting the PDA to CFG. Refer to [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/108668/102183) answer.

Comment: Huh? Took me 10 seconds to write down how to do it, and Acid probably not more than a minute to do it (and most of that time figuring out how to type an epsilon).

Comment: @gnasher729 maybe because you are more proficient at it?

Comment: @gnasher729 in case anyone of you has downvoted this question, please read the post again and do the needful

Comment: @gnasher729 I just pointed out a procedure to go about it. I personally had a hard time coming up with the grammars directly in the past.

Comment: @Infinity Yes, I am a cs undergrad at IITB.

Comment: @SiluPanda is there some other platform where I can contact you?

Comment: @Infinity I have given the link to my home page on my profile.

Comment: @SiluPanda it says this site can't be reached

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93037/discussion-between-silupanda-and-infinity).

Answer (score 0):

S-> aSb | bbb
A grammar G=(V,T,S,P) is defined as
V=s
T=a,b
S=s
P=aSb|bbb